# Is phone number required for providing phone warranties in Australia?

Tags: privacy, australia, warranties, phone

When buying a phone in retail store, they ask for my phone number so that they can "provide phone warranties". Is this an excuse to obtain my phone number for marketing purposes? Is it really required by law? In general, is personal identifiable information (PII) required for providing warranties? How can I buy a phone without providing them? I never trust how corporations handle PII, especially given the [recent data breach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optus#2022_cyberattack).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there is no requirement under Australian law, esepcially the ACL, that you must provide any PII for the warranty to apply.
However, most phone companies do require you provide proof of purchase to claim warranty, which in my opinion is proved by having the original receipt. Example:[Motorola Warranty](https://help.motorola.com/hc/apps/settings/legal/global/en-gb/index.html?t=CGT1507061106).

So, just decline the people asking for your phone number. When you need the warranty, go to the manufacturer's website first to return it, and if they ask for proof of purchase, present the original receipt. That should take care of it if your phone is in warranty.